# WKWebView - Ignore the right "safe area inset" in landscape view

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am fairly new to iOS development and I'm using a WKWebView to render my website. I am trying to add some constraints but want to ignore the right "safe area inset" in landscape view as marked in the screenshot.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

let customFrame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: self.webViewContainer.frame.size.height))
     
self.webView = WKWebView (frame: customFrame , configuration: webConfiguration)
       webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
    
    
addConstraints(to: webView, with: webViewContainer)

func addConstraints(to webView: UIView, with superView: UIView) {
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    superView.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use size classes and change the constraint like below in the image

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use storyboard to add constraints. Can you send me the corresponding Swift code?

Comment: Please send me the corresponding line of code.